# error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid provider: null

Tags: android-studio, locationmanager

anyone can help me? i got error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid provider: null. how to fix it? if i run in android version 4.4.4 it's fine, but if i run in android version 6.0.1, it's force close.

this is my code :

```
// fungsi ngecek lokasi GPS device pengguna
private void lokasi(){
    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }

    // permintaan update lokasi device dalam waktu 10 detik
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 10000, 1, this);
    if(location!=null){
        onLocationChanged(location);
        callListVolley(latitude, longitude);
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Lokasi device pengguna tidak ditemukan.\nMohon hidupkan GPS.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        swipe.setRefreshing(false);
    }
}
```

i also added android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION in manifest

Answer (score 0):

I have a some problem. And I solve it like bellow

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_location);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }

    // your codes
}
```

user need to allow location permission for the app to run from API Level 23 onwards.